# Run script on cron job every sunday except if sunday comes with 1 st date of the month

Tags: linux, suse

Customer requested to Run script on cron job every sunday  except if sunday comes with 1 st date of the month.

mentioned below My current schedule:

25 2 * * Sun

How can i change the cronjob for that

Any one can Help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot express compound conditions like that easily in the `crontab` specification.

What you have is good as far as `cron` is concerned. What I would do now is to either

- write a short shell snippet returning true/false given the day of the month, and chaining the command:  `isNotFirstDay && commandYouWantToRun`, or
- embed the day-of-month logic in the program or script you call every Sunday and have it skip if it is the first of the month

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date +%d` to get the day of month.

Run your script if the result not equals to '01'.

> 25 2 * * Sun [ $(date +%d) != "01" ] && myscript.sh